# PHP OOP How to call an object's parent method from the object itself?

Tags: php, oop

In PHP OOP, it is possible to call an object's parent method, by externally referencing that object?

```
Class ObjectOne {
    protected function method() {
        // Does something simple
    }
}

Class ObjectTwo extends ObjectOne {
    protected function method() {
        $temp = clone $this;
        $this->change_stuff();
        if(parent::method()) {
            // Do more stuff here
            $temp->method();
            // This will call this method, not the parent's method.
        }
    }

    protected function change_stuff() {
        // Change this object's stuff
    }
}
```

I can't call parent::method() because this will cause **the current object** to execute it's method. **I want the $temp ones's instead.**

**SOLVED**

I solved it by writing another function that calls the `parent::update()` method from inside the class:

```
Class ObjectOne {
    protected function method() {
        // Does something simple
    }
}

Class ObjectTwo extends ObjectOne {
    protected function method() {
        $temp = clone $this;
        $this->change_stuff();
        if(parent::method()) {
            // Do more stuff here
            $temp->update_parent();
            // This will call this method, not the parent's method.
        }
    }

    protected function change_stuff() {
        // Change this object's stuff
    }

    protected function update_parent() {
        return parent::update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`$temp->parent::update()` doesn't make sense.

Why not just do `parent::update()` again instead of `$temp->parent::update();`

You have two methods named `update()` If you call `$this->update()` it will call the method from the object that a call made from.
You can do

```
parent::update();
```

This will run `update()` method in `ObjectOne` class

Comment: I can't call `parent::update()` because this will cause the **current object** to save it's attributes to the database. I want the $temp ones's instead.

Comment: No, it won't. It will call the parent object's `update()` method if you do `parent::update()`

Comment: You are missing the point. I don't want this object to call the update() method, whether his or the parent's. I need $temp to call it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any protected and public parent methods, using the following syntax

```
parent::method_name();
```

In your case this will be:
    parent::update();